# PHP - Shift lines in txt file to restricted amount of lines

Tags: php, file

I am writing a chat in PHP and I want to restrict the amount of lines in a chat file:

```
<?php
    $filename = "chat.txt";

    file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($filename) . $_POST["message"] . "\r\n");

    $max_lines = 3;
    $lines = 0;

    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $line = fgets($handle);
      $lines++;
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $lines_over = $lines - $max_lines;
    if ($lines_over > 0) {
        while ($lines_over > 0) {
            file_put_contents($filename, implode("\r\n", file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)));

            $lines_over--;
        }
    }
?>
```

, I want to delete as many lines as needed in the beginning to make the file only have 3 lines.

Which apparently doesn't work with my current code and I don't know why, please help?

Comment: Your code create some errors?

Comment: @MarcoMura, no, but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Have you done some var dump to see if counters have got the right values?

Comment: @MarcoMura What is var dump?

Comment: print your vars (echo, print, print_r, etc...) to video

Comment: I would think using `file()` then manipulating the array would be better.  Then you can use `count()` and `array_shift()` or `array_slice()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully understand the logic you are trying use. If you want to delete lines from the beginning of the file you can use this. I have added explanation in the code.

```
$filename = "chat.txt";
$max_lines = 3;
//Read lines into an array
$lines = file($filename);
//trim your array to max_lines
$lines = array_slice($lines, -1 * $max_lines);
//check if we have max_lines
if (count($lines) == $max_lines){
    //remove one from the beginning
    array_shift($lines);
}
//add your new line
$lines[] = trim($_POST["message"]) . "\r\n";
file_put_contents($filename, implode($lines));
```

References: [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Edit: Another method without using `array_shift`

```
$filename = "chat.txt";
$max_lines = 3;
//Read lines into an array
$lines = file($filename);
//trim your array to just one less item than max lines
$lines = array_slice($lines, -1*($max_lines-1));
//confirm newline is available in the last line
$lines[count($lines)-1] = trim($lines[count($lines)-1]) . "\r\n";
//add your new line with newline
$lines[] = trim($_POST["message"]) . "\r\n";
file_put_contents($filename, implode($lines));
```

Edit2: Fixed issue with empty file and file not yet created.

```
$filename = "chat.txt";
$max_lines = 3;
//Read lines into an array only if file_exists
//On first run this file may not be there
if(file_exists($filename)){
    $lines = file($filename);
}
//trim your array to just one less item than max lines
//This is needed only if there are lines
if (!empty($lines)){
    $lines = array_slice($lines, -1*($max_lines-1));
    //confirm newline is available in the last line
    $lines[count($lines)-1] = trim($lines[count($lines)-1]) . "\r\n";
}
//add your new line with newline
$lines[] = trim($_POST["message"]) . "\r\n";
file_put_contents($filename, implode($lines));
```

Note: I have not added validation for preventing browser refresh and same message getting added multiple times. This is left for you to implement.

Comment: I would think you would only need `array_shift` if this is the only way the text file gets written.  No need to slice if the file only contains 3 lines to begin with.  Secondly, the `array_slice($lines, 0, 3)` is taking the first 3 lines, not the last 3.

Comment: I noticed that this won't work if I edit the file manually to ex 10 rows?

Comment: In the way that i't won't add a newline char in the end

Comment: This will work even if the file is manually edited and added more lines. That is why i have used `array_slice` and then `array_shift`. You can avoid the `count` and `array_shift` with bit more intelligent use of `array_slice`

Comment: @bansi Noticed that if I make the whole file empty, when I call send a message the first time, the message will come at the second row, it should appear at the first.

Comment: <EMPTY LINE> <BR>
first message <BR>
second message

Comment: Nice catch. Added validation. The code was just typed in here not tested. The last edit i have tested it.